# Run MS Access mdb with task scheduler

Tags: ms-access, taskscheduler

I want to simply open an MS Access MDB file with task scheduler, but it just says "running" and leaves MS Access open in the background which I can only see in the task manager.

I have an AutoExec macro that does it's thing and then closes itself. Works fine opening the program manually, doesn't do anything when opened from task scheduler (Including clicking run on the task myself).

I've seen many ask this online, but have found no solutions.

Here's what I have in the Task Scheduler:

Program/Script: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE"`

Add arguments (optional): `C:\[TheDirectory]\SCServerData.mdb`

I have other Task Scheduled .bat files that run with no problem.

Comment: please provide us command that you use to run your base in scheduler

Comment: It probably runs under a different user account than when run manually, and so it may have different / missing access rights to network resources etc., like linked tables.

Comment: Are you using QuitAccess in addition to CloseDatabase as the final macro steps?

Comment: It doesn't even start running the function called by the AutoExec macro. I'll add the code and command above.

Comment: I've added the command I have in Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's quite simple actually. I just put the command in a batch file instead and run that with Task Scheduler. Seems to be working so far.